# Sql Connection refuses to connect when using Mono

Tags: c#, mono, ado.net, system.data

I have created a simple program to illustrate problem. I have a console application that should connect to a external SQL Server instance.

Locally I can connect to this host just fine (whether the  be set to the IP address or the external URL that the server is associated with via DNS). When I copy the compiled version of the application over to a Ubuntu server with Mono installed and run the application using `mono ConsoleApplication1.exe`, I am presented with this error everytime:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Server does not exist or
>   connection refused.   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open ()
>   <0x409d4e90 + 0x0053f> in :0   at
>   ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main (System.String[] args) <0x409a7d50 +
>   0x00077> in :0 [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Server does not exist or
>   connection refused.   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open ()
>   <0x409d4e90 + 0x0053f> in :0   at
>   ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main (System.String[] args) <0x409a7d50 +
>   0x00077> in :0

I have tried using a direct IP to the SQL Server instance and also the external URL (in place of  below), which I know works locally running this application.

The code used to setup in the application:

App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Test" connectionString="data source=<Host>\<Instance Name>, 1069;database=<Database Name>;user id=<User>;password=<Password>;multipleactiveresultsets=True;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

C# Code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test"].ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Connected");
        }
    }
}
```

Environment:

- SQL Server: Windows 2012 DC with SQL Server 2014 Instance
- Mono Environment: Ubuntu 16.04 running Latest Mono-Complete
- .NET Version: 4.6.2 (also tried 4.5.2)

**Update:**
I can confirm that using FreeTDS I can connect to the instance of SQL Server from the Ubuntu instance, so the problem seems isolated to running the application.

Comment: Is any other software on your Ubuntu system able to connect?

Comment: Thus far I have verified the Ubuntu machine can telnet that host and that port and get a response, I'm going to try use something like free tds to see can establish a TSQL connection

Comment: Does your SQLServer log show the connection? Any error?

Comment: Did you check if TCP/IP is enabled and port 1433  is open in firewall ? `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager12.msc`

Comment: @SushiHangover I have enabling the audit logs for any attempt to log in and can see there are no logs made when I attempt to establish a connection

Comment: @Searching I have setup a custom port for the SQL Server however I have turned the entire firewall off to test whether it was a firewall problem and this had no effect on connecting

Comment: @Dai I can confirm that using Free TDS and the TSQL command that I can connect to the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to spin up another Linux instance (Debian this time) to see if it could possibly be an environment issue. I installed the latest mono, etc. Running the same application actually gave me more information then running on the Ubuntu instance:

```
Server does not exist or connection refused. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Could not resolve host '<Host>\<Instance Name>'
```

Previously I did not get the extra `SocketException` stating that it could not resolve the host. I don't know why I didn't get this information on the Ubuntu instance.

This led me to remove the `Instance Name` off of the connection string. As soon as this was done, the application started working as expected.

Comment: When you removed the Instance Name, did you retain the rest of the connection string "as-is"? Does the updated version work in both Ubuntu and Linux?

Comment: From what I recall (testing my memory) I left it as is aside from removing the instance name. This was in a Ubuntu instance 16.04 at the time, I can't speak for how it would be in any other distro. Sorry can't be much more use

Comment: thanks. I have the same issue, but in my case removing the instance name didn't help. It just changed the error message to `"Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.TdsInternalException: Server closed the connection....`